# Bachelier Normal Implied Vol Python Calculation (Help) Jekel

Tags: python-3.x, quantitative-finance, gamma-function, computational-finance

Writing a python script to calc Implied Normal Vol ; in line with Jekel article (Industry Standard).

https://jaeckel.000webhostapp.com/ImpliedNormalVolatility.pdf

They say they are using a Generalized Incomplete Gamma Function Inverse.

For a call:

F(x)=v/(K - F) -> find x that makes this true

Where F is Inverse Incomplete Gamma Function

And x = (K - F)/(T*sqrt(T) ; v is the value of a call

for that x, IV is =(K-F)/x*sqrt(T)

Example I am working with:

F=40

X=38

T=100/365

v=5.25

Vol= 20%

Using the equations I should be able to backout Vol of 20%

Scipy has upper and lower Incomplete Gamma Function Inverse in their special functions.

Lower: scipy.special.gammaincinv(a, y)  : {a must be positive param}

Upper: scipy.special.gammainccinv(a, y) : {a must be positive param}

```
Implementation:

SIG= sympy.symbols('SIG')
F=40
T=100/365
K=38

def Objective(sig):
    SIG=sig
    return(special.gammaincinv(.5,((F-K)**2)/(2*T*SIG**2))+special.gammainccinv(.5,((F-K)**2)/(2*T*SIG**2))+5.25/(K-F))

x=optimize.brentq(Objective, -20.00,20.00, args=(), xtol=1.48e-8, rtol=1.48e-8, maxiter=1000, full_output=True)


IV=(K-F)/x*T**.5

Print(IV)
```

I know I am wrong, but Where am I going wrong / how do I fix it and use what I read in the article ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you also post this on the [Quantitative Finance Stack Exchange](https://quant.stackexchange.com/)? You may get a better response there.

This is not my field, but it looks like your main problem is that [brentq](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.brentq.html) requires the passed `Objective` function to return values with opposite signs when passed the `-20` and `20` arguments. However, this will not end up happening because according to the scipy docs, [gammaincinv](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.gammaincinv.html) and [gammainccinv](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.gammainccinv.html#scipy.special.gammainccinv) always return a value between 0 and infinity.

I'm not sure how to fix this, unfortunately. Did you try implementing the analytic solution (rather than iterative root finding) in the second part of the paper?

Comment: Looked at second part of paper: abbreviating incomplete gamma function & inverse to gam_inc_inv for this converstion as it is long to type.... 

He calcs gam_inc_inv(-9/4) confused as I thought this can only take positive numbers? Not sure where he got -9/4 suppose it was just picked for the illustration.

Comment: Next the gam_inc_inv in pyton is the inverse of the regularized upper and lower gamma_inc; which is not what is needed as he is using the generalized gam_inc_inv (Z, 0, inf).

I have no idea what gam_inc_inv (subscript C) is or how you would know ahead of calculating that gam_inc_inv* < gam_inc_inv (subscript C)

His Eta function has a bunch of decimal values in it, where did those numbers come from?

Comment: had to add the comments above in 2 pieces, kind of long but a lot of questions.

Comment: Reworked it, analytical and moved to Quant Stack...hope I can sort this out. Thanks.